# Tensorflow Object Detection API 2

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tf object detection api 2.

After training the model you can run an evaluation process to check the accuracy of the model.
But when I tried to run I got the below error. I'm using the backbone as an efficientDet.
I was able to run the evaluation for scaling resolution 512 but 640 is failing with the below error.

This is the python file I called and ended up with the below error.
`enter code here` /tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py

```
`enter code here`enter code here`Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 480, 640, 3), dtype=float32)
  • kwargs={'training': 'False'}


exception.
INFO:tensorflow:A replica probably exhausted all examples. Skipping pending examples on other replicas.
I0719 06:49:27.115007 140042699994880 model_lib_v2.py:943] A replica probably exhausted all examples. Skipping pending e
xamples on other replicas.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pictcompute/effient_net_ve/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 115, in <m
odule>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/home/pictcompute/effient_net_ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/pictcompute/effient_net_ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/pictcompute/effient_net_ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/pictcompute/effient_net_ve/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 82, in mai
n
    model_lib_v2.eval_continuously(
  File "/home/pictcompute/effient_net_ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 1159, in ev
al_continuously
    eager_eval_loop(
  File "/home/pictcompute/effient_net_ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 1009, in ea
ger_eval_loop
    for evaluator in evaluators:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Highly appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when you try to iterate over a None value. For example

```
mylist = None
for x in mylist:
    print(x)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a63d8b17c4a7> in <module>
      1 mylist = None
      2 
----> 3 for x in mylist:
      4     print(x)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The error can be avoided by checking if a value is None or not before iterating over it. Thank You.